# Undefined Variable $subview codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Hi I'm Trying to create a CMS system but when i try to call the `$subview` from the controller to the view file with this it show an error

```
    Severity: Notice

    Message: Undefined variable: subview

    Filename: admin/_layout_main.php
```

Here is the controller file

```
<?php
class User extends Admin_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

    }


    public function index ()
    {
        // Fetch all users
        $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();
        // Load view
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }


    public function edit($id = NULL){

    }
    public function delete($id){
    }
    public function login() {

    $dashboard = 'admin/dashboard'; 
    $this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE || redirect($dashboard); 

    $rules= $this->user_m->rules;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
    if ($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE) {
    if ($this->user_m->login()==TRUE){
        redirect($dashboard);
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error'. 'That Email & Password Combination does exist'); 
            redirect('admin/user/login','refresh');
        }
    }
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/login';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal',$this->data);
    }

    public function logout(){
    $this->user_m->logout();
    redirect('admin/user/login');
    }


}
```

my view file _layout_main.php this is where i try to call the $subview

```
<?php $this->load->view('admin/components/page_head')?>
<body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
              <a class="brand" href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard');?>"><?php echo $meta_title;?></a>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard')?>">Dashboard</a></li>
              <li><?php echo anchor('admin/page','pages')?></li>
              <li><?php echo anchor('admin/users','users')?></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

<div class = "container">
<div class = "row">
<!-- Main Column -->
    <div class ="span9">


    <?php $this->load->view($subview); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
         <div class ="span3">
             <section>
              <?php echo mailto('********@gmail.com','<i class="icon-user"></i>********@gmail.com');?><br>
             <?php echo anchor('admin/user/logout','<i class="icon-off"></i>logout');?> 
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>      
<?php $this->load->view('admin/components/page_tail')?>
```

appreciate your help thank you

Comment: in which function you are calling view using `$this->load->view($subview);`?

Comment: add your admin/_layout_main.php code also

Comment: in the _layout_main is just call the subview with this                      <?php $this->load->view($subview); ?>

Comment: are you using template for view?

Comment: i updated my post .. i include the _layout_main my view file

Answer (score 0):

You are setting view path like

```
$data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index';
```

and you are loading

```
$this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);
```

Note that your layout is in admin and you are sending view path incorrectly. Path should be `user/index`.
I think this is the problem.

So your view path should be

```
$data['subview'] = 'user/index';
```

Comment: still show an error but when i try to load the view manually in the view file _layout_main                                                        <?php $this->load->view('admin/user/index)';?>                                  the view show

Comment: i updated my post and add the _layout_main thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this exact thing! If this is from the same tutorial on YouTube by Van Ray Hosea Gultom that is. There was already an `index()` function in the dashboard controller and since we were calling the `_layout_main` view twice the `include_once()` was not allowing that. I moved this code:

```
    $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index';
```

from `index()` in the user controller page into `index()` in the dashboard controller page.
I am pretty new to this and I am not sure if this was the correct way honestly but it solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You described main as your view file,but u pass it to layout_main
check it out

layout_model or layout_main

Comment: This is a question not an answer